# Faster XPath expressions to execute queries from multiple XMLs

Tags: xpath, xquery, xpath-2.0, xpath-3.0

I have the two following XMLs and the problem statement is as follows.

1. Parse XML 1 and if subnode of any **node_x** contains 'a' in its name (like in **value_a_0**) and **value_a_0** contains a specific number, parse XML 2 and go to **node_x-1** for all **abc_x** in  and compare the content of **value_x-1_0/1/2/3** with certain entities.
2. If subnode of any **node_x** contains 'b' in its name (like in **value_b_0**) and **value_b_0** contains a specific number(say 'm'), parse XML 2 and go to **node_x+1** for all **abc_x** in  and compare the content of **value_x-1_0/1/2/3** with 'm'.

Example : For all the **value_a_0** in **record1** check if **value_a_0** node contains 5. If so, which are the case for **node_1** and **node_9**, go to **record2/node_0** and **record2/node_8** and compare the contents of value_0_0/1/2/3 whether they contains 5 or not. Similarly, for rest of the cases.

I was wondering what would be the best practice to solve it? Is there any hash-table approach in Xpath 3.0?

**First XML**

```
<record1>
    <node_1>
        <value_a_0>5</value_1_0>
        <value_b_1>0</value_1_1>
        <value_c_2>10</value_1_2>
        <value_d_3>8</value_1_3>
    </node_1>
   .................................
   .................................

    <node_9>
        <value_a_0>5</value_a_0>
        <value_b_1>99</value_b_1>
        <value_c_2>53</value_c_2>
        <value_d_3>5</value_d_3>
  </node_9>
</record1>
```

**Second XML**

```
<record2>
  <abc_0>
        <node_0>
            <value_0_0>5</value_0_0>
            <value_0_1>0</value_0_1>
            <value_0_2>150</value_0_2>
            <value_0_3>81</value_0_3>
        </node_0>
        <node_1>
            <value_1_0>55</value_1_0>
            <value_1_1>30</value_1_1>
            <value_1_2>150</value_1_2>
            <value_1_3>81</value_1_3>
        </node_1>
       .................................
       .................................

        <node_63>
            <value_63_0>1</value_63_0>
            <value_63_1>99</value_63_1>
            <value_63_2>53</value_63_2>
            <value_63_3>5</value_63_3>
      </node_63>
   </abc_0>
   ================================================
   <abc_99>
        <node_0>
            <value_0_0>555</value_0_0>
            <value_0_1>1810</value_0_1>
            <value_0_2>140</value_0_2>
            <value_0_3>80</value_0_3>
        </node_0>            
        <node_1>
            <value_1_0>555</value_1_0>
            <value_1_1>1810</value_1_1>
            <value_1_2>140</value_1_2>
            <value_1_3>80</value_1_3>
        </node_1>
        <node_2>
            <value_2_0>5</value_2_0>
            <value_2_1>60</value_2_1>
            <value_2_2>10</value_2_2>
            <value_2_3>83</value_2_3>
        </node_2>
       .................................
       .................................

        <node_63>
            <value_63_0>1</value_63_0>
            <value_63_1>49</value_63_1>
            <value_63_2>23</value_63_2>
            <value_63_3>35</value_63_3>
       </node_63>
    </abc_99>
  </record2>
```

Comment: Your samples like `<value_a_0>5</value_1_0>` are not even well-formed. In general the structure you have there is a poor use of XML. On the other hand, if you want to "compare" certain elements by their value I think this is a grouping task you address in XQuery 3 and later with `for ... group by`, as certainly described in any XQuery tutorial or book.

Comment: This question is confusing, not well defined.

Please, work on expressing a question with clarity, so that the chances are good someone will understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a task that can partially solved by grouping but as in your previous examples the poor use of XML elements names that all differ by index values that should be part of an element or attribute value and not part of the element name makes it harder to write succinct code:

```
let $abc-elements := $doc2/record2/*
for $node-element in record1/*
for $index in (1 to count($node-element[1]/*))
for $index-element in $node-element/*[position() = $index]
group by $index, $group-value := $index-element
where tail($index-element)
return 
    <group index="{$index}" value="{$group-value}">
    {
        let $suffixes := $index-element/../string((xs:integer(substring-after(local-name(), '_')) - 1)),
            $relevant-abc-node-elements := $abc-elements/*[substring-after(local-name(), '_') = $suffixes]
        return $relevant-abc-node-elements[* = $group-value]
    }
    </group>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kA

Answer (score 4):

First I would say that using structured element names like this is pretty poor XML design. That's relevant because when you do a join query in XPath or XQuery you're very dependent on the optimizer to find a fast execution path (e.g. a hash join), and the "weirder" your query is, the less likely the optimizer is to find a fast execution strategy.

I often start by converting "weird" XML into something more sanitary. For example in this case I would transform `<value_a_0>5</value_1_0>` into `<value cat="a" seq="0">5</value>`. That makes it easier to write your query and easier for the optimizer to recognize it, and the transformation phase is re-usable so you can apply it before any operations on the XML, not just this one.

If you're looking for better than O(n*m) performance on a join query, you need to look at the capabilities of your chosen XPath engine. Saxon-EE for example will do such optimizations, Saxon-HE won't. You're generally more likely to find advanced optimization in an XQuery engine than an XPath engine.

As for the detail of your query, I got lost with the requirement statement when you start talking about `abc_x`. I'm not sure what that refers to.

Comment: abc_x means x ranging from 0 to 99 in <record2>.